# How is service discovery not a subset of centralized configuration?

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, service-discovery, consul, consensus

I'm looking at consensus-type tools like [ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/), [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) and [Eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka) and they all seem to market the same set of solutions:

- Service discovery
- Dynamic, centralized configuration management
- Synchronization primitives
- Consensus algorithms

However the more I read about these things, the more I struggle to see how **service discovery** is really any different than a dynamic, centralized **configuration management (KV pair) system**.

My *understanding* (so far) of service discovery is that it allows nodes to dynamically search for, find and connnect to remote services. So if an application uses an `AuthService` for authentication, authorization, it would use service discovery to find an `AuthService` node at, say, `http://auth103.example.org:9103` and use it.

My *understanding* of dynamic config systems is that they provide a centralized infrastructure for nodes to dynamically receive updates from, as well as publish updates to, config servers. So if an app instance decides it needs to update a configuration for all its other instances, it would contact the config service and update, say, the `numPurgerThreads` config. The config service would then update all other app instances so that they updated their respective configs properly.

**But aren't these exactly the same problem?**

In both cases, you:

1. Connect to a lookup service of some sort
2. Query it for data; or
3. Publish data to it, which then ripples out to other nodes

Service discovery *is* dynamic configuration, right?!?!

What I'm really driving at is: **Couldn't I just implement one config service with one of these tools, which coincidentally also solves service discovery?** Or is there a reason why I would need to have, say, 1 Consul cluster for config/KV management, and another, say, Consul cluster for service discovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you look at it like that, these are all just flavors of databases, or data stores if you will, as you describe it:

```
Connect to a lookup service of some sort
Query it for data; or
Publish data to it, which then ripples out to other nodes
```

All of the use cases you mentioned require some sort of a data store that multiple clients connect to. What makes some of them more optimal then others for different use cases is their interface, data model, consistency guaranties etc.

Specifically, in case of service discovery, a nice feature can be failure detection - e.g. a k/v store that allows removing service data when the service is no longer connected. This way, you can register a service to your service discovery tool and know that when the service goes down or looses connectivity, it will no longer be present in the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify a few terms, (imo) dynamic config systems can update their state at runtime, in contrast to static where everything is defined beforehand (i.e. config files). *Centralized CM* means there's a single place to store all config data. So centralized CM can both be static or dynamic, right?

IMO, service discovery has a component which CM doesn't and that's **a protocol** for automatic detection of services.

Guess you'd need a dynamic CM (KV store) to implement service discovery, but you couldn't implement a CM store just using a service discovery (protocol). Take [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) for example (hope we agree it is a service discovery protocol?) -  Dynamic Host **Configuration** Protocol', so it has a configuration aspect, but also a protocol, which is a bit more than a simple KV store. Btw, it's decentralized, just to illustrate the previous point that CM doesn't have to be centralized..

So service discovery has a configuration aspect, but CM doesn't (necessarily) have a service discovery one. Does this mean SD is a subset of CM? I'd say no.